# The accessibilityHint gets appended in the "accesibility id" in the appium inspector

Tags: react-native, appium, accessibility, end-to-end

When I am trying to add `accessibilityLabel` without `accessibilityHint`, I'm getting error that `has accessibilityLabel prop but no accessibilityHinteslint(react-native-a11y/has-accessibility-hint)`. But on adding `accessibilityHint` it is being appended in the `accessibility id` in Appium inspector. like the following:

[image: accessibility id in appium inspector having accessibilityHint appended after accessibilityLabel]
Just want to know if there a way to stop `accessibilityHint` from getting appended in the accessibilityLabel?